# Custom fields are not exported using Studio's exporting tool - SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm experimenting an issue when I export customizations made by Studio tool, any custom fields are not exporting. I mean, when I load the package created in developer server to the production server, there are not custom fields in EditView, there are "native" fields only.

I'm using SugarCRM 6.1.6 (I know, it is an old version, but I can't update it right now)

Regards

Mauricio M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just need to do a repair and rebuild - that's the likely quick fix. Alternatively, ensure that the package on the dev server exported both the custom fields and the custom layout metadata (i.e. the edit and detail view layouts). If it did, double check the permissions in custom/modules//metadata to ensure that the files were able to be uploaded and are readable by the web server.